# Angular 2 List Filter

Tags: angular

I've built an Angular 2 list filter by providing a text input before, but it was before the new `@angular/forms` module shipped and I haven't updated it yet. I started a new project recently that uses the new forms module, and I can't figure out why what I'm doing isn't working.

It's simple: a text input with an `[(ngModel)]` set on it, with that `ngModel` variable passed into my custom pipe to filter the list. It really isn't that hard. But here's the HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" #filterForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-5">Filter List</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <input type="text" name="filterText" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="filterObj.match">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Just a basic `form`. Without the `form` element, I was getting an error for putting `ngModel` on the `input`.

Then in the to print out the list:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of list | filter:filterObj">{{item.title}}</li>
```

The issue is that even with that `ngModel` set on the `input` no changes are detected and the list never updates. I confirmed by putting an `ngOnChanges` function in the class to watch for that variable and it never changes.

Has anyone else had this issue with the new `@angular/forms` release?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: There is no error message, the variable just isn't updated when you type anything into the field. Before I wrapped the input in a form, it was a template syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

To debug this try to decouple `ngModel` like this:

```
<input [value]="currentHero.firstName"
       (input)="currentHero.firstName=$event.target.value" >
```

Comment: Still nothing happens when doing it your suggested way or by: `<input ... [ngModel]="variable" (ngModelChange)="variable=$event">`